# In 1000 years, could a magnetic bottle-like plasma dome system protect a small city?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, far-future, protection

I've looked at the magnetic bottle (hydrogen plasma/fusion) idea as a potential basis for extrapolating what technology might be capable of doing with plasma fields 1000 years into the future...which is when my novel is set...but I'm worried about the heat it might give off, as well as the large electromagnetic field needed, which could cause the people inside or within a certain radius of the dome to be killed. Additionally, a magnetic bottle would be disrupted by the interference of the soil/ground, if it were just one magnetic bottle per dome.  Maybe a series of magnetic bottle-like plasma fields - vertically or horizontally arranged - in a dome-like shape could work?

Comment: Plasma?  It would be like living inside the sun itself, and your heatsinks are trying to absorb/divert the heat of the sun.  Science-based this just seems weird.  We would have to first solve what prevents the plasma from causing the air around it to excite instantly into something close to a nuclear explosion.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand our standards, then rework your question. As it is now it is too broad (we prefer 1 well defined question per post), unclear (what do you mean with "adding an electromagnetic charge"?) and also opinion based (in 1000 years we don't know what the tech level will be or if we will still be there).

Comment: Also, the earth with its magnetic field and ionosphere (which is plasma) is essentially what you are describing.

Comment: Thank you, Mathaddict - I will look into those similarities when designing a protective dome.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: To figure out what will be possible in a thousand years, see what people from thousand years ago predicted properly about today. Or people in the \`30s or \`50s, really. Then you will see the impossibility of such predictions.

Comment: @Molot...understood...but I have to convince people of our time to suspend disbelief that such tech could be in our future.  So, I would like to steer away from “complete impossibility” if I can.  I will, however, take your suggestion to go back to 30s tech and think about that comparison.  It’s just one of those things where “everyone knows” deflector shields a la Star Trek have no basis in current science...so my dome shield is an instant point of scrutiny for many sci-fi fans.

Comment: What are you trying to protect your city from?

Comment: Please update your question to state exactly what kind of setup you want, what it is for, and what your concerns are. As of now i cannot figure out where the plasma is supposed to be, why it would be there, for what reason, and what magnetic bottles have to fo with it.

Comment: I am trying to protect the city from unwanted visitors in the form of people and genetically altered animals and plants.  Whether or not the dome can stop a round of ammo is negotiable.  Thank you for all of your responses.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR You would have a fancy city sized crock pot

You would need to replace your atmosphere inside the dome with liquid nitrogen in order to keep the steel in the buildings from igniting.  While there are states of plasma that don't burn hot as the sun, they would be about as useful to protect a city as wet toilet paper seeing as they are not dense enough to stop solid objects. If you had the plasma hot enough to protect your city it would need to be able to heat metal up enough to melt or at least deform it, which is insanely high for most metals. I didn't do the math, (If someone wants to comment it feel free.) but lets just say it would take several thousand k to melt even a small car enough to stop its function. It gets worse too, as if your city is attacked by ballistic ammo it will be going somewhere between fast, (792 meters per second in the case of [a 3 inch m5 cannon from WW2,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-inch_Gun_M5)) to [Ludicrous speed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygE01sOhzz0) (2,520 meters per second the case of the navy's new rail-gun). At these speeds you would either need a much thicker plasma wall or much hotter plasma in order to melt the round. Although this would just spread melted steel and lead like a shotgun, so you would want to make it hot enough to evaporate. Lead evaporates when it reaches 1750c(3182f), and iron roughly 3134c(5673.2f).  If your city has walls this hot, you will not have a city, you'll have a gaseous crater.  I also think containment would be a problem, as the magnets might rip the hemoglobin out of your body due to how strong they would have to be and any electronic within the city would instantly fry.